How stop indexing feed and html urls in sitemap?
As you see in below images there are many urls with feed format or html format and also ?a=236568198 format which should not be in sitemap. There are many errors in pages in Search Console like Page with redirect or Crawed currently not indexed and there wont solve anyway!
Need help to fix these issues



Firstly, it's important to know that these are not necessarily errors, just information about the URLs Google have found for your site.
Your XML sitemap (generated by  Rank Math WordPress SEO Plugin) currently contains all those feeds for your tag pages.  Beyond spending crawl budget, it's unlikely they are doing any harm. However, if you do want to stop Google crawling them, you need to remove them from the sitemap, and tell Google not to crawl them in your robots.txt file.  The latter will probably suffice, but doing both is tidier.
The pages with the a parameter don't appear to be internally generated.  If you look at your backlinks, you'll probably find that these are coming from somewhere like affiliate or advert links.  As long as the landing page itself has appropriate an canonical tag, these won't be doing any harm to SEO.  I would not block them, as they will have SEO benefit.
